# Arranging numbers/letters in different combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have a question regarding the combination of numbers (or letters etc.).

I have two problems that I can solve by counting, but I do not understand how I could potentially formulate these calculations in a mathematical way.

Problem 1: In how many ways can three numbers/letters be arranged, if you would want to arrange them as pairs?
My solution for this problem is 9. I have achieved this result by taking the factorial of 2, multiplying it by 3 and adding 3. Is there a better way?

Problem 2: In how many ways can two numbers/letters be arranged if you would want to arrange them  as triplets (3-tuples).
My solution is 8 (by counting) but I don´t know how to solve this in mathematical way.

I would appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "arrange them as pairs" ? There are a few ways of interpreting this, but none of those interpretations get me to $9$. So, I'm curious as to what you mean by "arrange them as pairs".

Comment: By combining them as pairs I´ve assumed the following: Assume we have the letters A, B and C. Then we would get the 9 following pairs: AA, BB, CC,  AB, BA, BC, CB, AC, CA. Maybe I should have mentioned that I also want the pairs of the same letters included (e.g. AA BB and CC).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the multiplication principle or [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  Note that $3 \cdot 3=9$ for your first example and $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2=8$ for the second.  As a more complex example, California license plates are one digit, three letters, and three digits.  This gives $10 \cdot 26^3 \cdot 10^3$ possibilities.